# Reshaping matrix in N dimensions octave

Tags: matrix, octave, reshape

would appreciate feedback on how to reshape general ND matrix from a file in octave. To set the problem,
if I read data like for 2D case x y z

```
    0 10 13
    0 11 -1
    0 12 12
    1 10 5
    1 11 4
    1 12 3
    2 10 1
    2 11 6
    2 12 2
```

reading Z values

```
matrix = dlmread('data.dat');
z = matrix(:,3);
z = reshape(z, 3, 3).';
x = [0 1 2];
y = [10 11 12];

xi = linspace (min (x), max (x), 200);
yi = linspace (min (y), max (y), 300);
fcn = interpn (x, y, A, xi, yi, "spline");
```

Now, transposing a matrix doesn't work in ND which here needs to be done. How would one do a ND case pulling from data so to format this for interpn,

thanks, Damir

Comment: [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) is the nD generalization of the matrix transpose.

Comment: Thanks!; I'm just looking at this Matlab example https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interpn.html where one transposes the vector itself; How would you go about this for 4D, 5D case; reshape or transposing in octave.